# Prove the theorem by binding the term and splitting the sum

Tags: summation, algorithms

I am having trouble understanding the basics of proving theorems by binding the term and splitting the sum. Below is a simple theorem that I am trying to prove with the bind/split technique...

[a simple theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jJtJ.jpg)

I seriously have no clue where to start. I understand how to use induction and whatnot but again, I'm seriously lost on this. Any dummy-level help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think by "bind" you might mean "bound". To bound something is to supply bounds for it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: "Binding the term" is a method for finding the lower or upper bounds of a sum, from what I know. But yes, I need to find the bounds for this term.

Comment: @JoeBalin Thanks for asking this question. I am also taking Chris Marriott's algorithms course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $$1^5 + \dots + n^5 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^5 = \frac{2n^6 + 6n^5 + 5n^4 -n^2}{12}.$$ Now recall the definition of $g(n) \in \Omega(f(n)).$

> **Definition.** A function $g(n) \in \Omega(f(n))$ if $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N},c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $n \geq n_0$ then $$g(n) \geq cf(n).$$

Now, $$g(n) = \frac{2n^6 + 6n^5 + 5n^4 -n^2}{12} \geq \frac{1}{6}n^6$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ so take $n_1 = 1$ and $c = \frac{1}{6}$. Likewise we can prove that $g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n^6)$ (exercise) and we can conclude that $g(n) \in \Theta(n^6)$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which of these steps is considered "binding the term" or "splitting the sum"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply say that $i^5 \leq n^5$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, and so $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^5 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n n^5 = n^6$$

Therefore the ratio $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^5}{n^6}$$ is always at most $1$ as $n \to \infty$.